# jQuery replaceWith weird behaviour on replacing table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've come across some strange behaviour with jQuery and I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

I've managed to work around it, but I had pulling my hair out for days with it.

Here's a jsFiddle for you... http://jsfiddle.net/YZxzy/3/

The issue seems to be replacing the `<tr>` with `<input ... /> <tr> .. <tr>`.  however, this will render correctly.

To be clear, having:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <input type="hidden" .... />
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

will render correctly in the browser, but I cannot create this using the jQuery "replaceWith" action.

Now, I KNOW that this is not well formed, and it is bad practice, the question is NOT how do I fix it.  I know that I can fix it by adding the `<input>` into the  and I also know that it SHOULD be in a .  The question is:

Why does the jQuery `.replaceWith()` not allow you to do the above, even though a browser will render it correctly?

Comment: It's difficult to predict how each browser will react to invalid nesting. Some will let it work in some cases, and not in others, however a completely different browser may handle both differently. What kind of answer are you expecting to this question? I can't think of an answer other than "thats how the browser vender decided to handle invalid nesting" which is pretty obvious imo.

Comment: it's not a browser thing, it's a jQuery thing, I want to know why jQuery is removing the <tr> and <td> elements in that code.

Comment: jQuery is not removing it, the browser is. jQuery is using `.innerHTML` which is a method defined by the javascript engine being used by the browser.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should be using the jQuery function to construct new elements, not string concatenation.

Comment: so you're saying that the .InnerHtml method is detecting that I'm trying to insert a <input> element into a <tbody>?

Comment: You can look at how jQuery does it yourself here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/manipulation.js#L628 it creates a document fragment, appends a div to it, then uses innerHTML to add your passed in html, then it gets the contents of the div and puts them where you requested for them to be placed.

Comment: The point i'm getting at is jquery is not taking your html string and modifying it. It detects that it isn't a simple string such as "<div>". If it isn't simple, it creates a dom fragment, appends a div, sets the content of that div to your html string using innerHTML, gets the content, and inserts it. If the resulting content is different from the string you passed in, the string you passed in probably wasn't valid ( as in your case ).

Comment: @Martin : You're forgetting that any change to the DOM can create a reflow. When the DOM tries to parse the string as you gave it, it comes across an invalid node, first, attempts to add that node, and then moves to the next piece. Finding it has a fragment (a tr without a directly-preceding table, tbody or thead) with no valid parent, my guess is that it gets interpreted as a string at that point. The whole DOM has to reflow, based on that interpretation, which is why it no longer resembles a table row at that point.

Comment: @KevinB what I'm trying to understand then is if jQuery fires "<input>.. <tr>... <tr> ..." at the innerHTML action of the javascript engine, does it also give it context? as in how does the JS Engine know that <input> isn't valid? does it also send the parent?

Comment: Additionally, putting an <input> in the HTML directly, renders OK, it's only when dynamically adding it via jQuery that this happens.  Why doesn't the browser throw a hissy fit when the page loads?

Comment: At this point, I must exit. I can't explain why the browser engines are making those choices, unfortunately.  I'll be watching this thread, though, as I'd be interested if someone more knowledgeable about HTML parsing engines can answer! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are a few things wrong with this script.

Here's my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/b3wfY/

For one thing, you're going to start running into a mess of trouble when this starts getting big, as you're clobbering the DOM only to re-add something that already exists. There's no good reason to replace AddNewRows only to re-add it. You should be using .before() to insert the new row, instead.

```
$("#AddRows").click(function () {
    $("#AddNewRows").before(
        '<tr id="row3"><input type="hidden" value="33" id="hiddenRow3" /><td>Value 3.1</td><td>Value 3.2</td></tr>');
});
```

Secondly, as soon as I moved your hidden field inside the row, it started working. Why? Because `<input/>` tags are not valid where you placed them... `<table/>` tags can contain tbody, thead, tr, and a couple other tags, but input is invalid. This was throwing the rendering off. If you place the hidden input field inside the row, however, that's valid placement... actually, better would be to place it inside a td tag, I think, but this started working as soon as I got it inside the tr.

Comment: The example I posted is a much more simplified version of what I was actually doing, I actually don't have the ability to put it in a `<td>` as it's generated by a bit of code that I don't control. That's why I'm not looking for a "fix".  Yes the code I supplied is bad code, it was just trying to illustrate the problem I was facing by some auto-generated code.

Comment: I believe that the issue (from the comments) is that `<input>` is actually a valid descendant of `<tr>` but not of `<tbody>`.  The thing I'm struggling with is, what exactly strips all the data Firefox, the jQuery code? is it a browser feature or jQuery?

Comment: From what the other posters/commenters were saying, I'm betting on the browser, as jQuery under the hood can only call the native APIs, it's up to the browser how to actually implement. Good luck, though!